# Nested Fragment with backstack Resume

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack, android-nested-fragment

In my application there are several `fragment`s in an `activity` and I am maintaining a `backStack` for these `fragment`. Everything is okay, but there is a nested fragment among them. When I put it into `backStack` and again resume in by pressing back button, the fragment looks overllaping previous content (child fragment). 
This is the normal view:

[image]

This is the screenshot of overlapping view (when I resume the fragment):

[image]

You can get the difference as the second one's text is more deep (that means child fragment is overlapping)

How can I avoid that? This the code for my nested fragment:

```
public class CompetitiveProgramming extends SherlockProgressFragment implements
        OnChapterSelectListener, OnSubChapterSelectListener {

    View mContentView;
    static public List<Chapter> chapterList = new ArrayList<Chapter>();
    private ProcessTask processTask = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mContentView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.competitive_programming_exercise, container, false);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setContentShown(false);
        setContentView(mContentView);
        processTask = new ProcessTask();
        processTask.execute();
    }


    protected class ProcessTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // background task
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            if (mContentView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
                getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.fragment_container, new ChaptersListFragment()).commit();
            } else {
                transaction.add(R.id.category_fragment, new ChaptersListFragment());
                transaction.add(R.id.sub_category_fragment, new SubChaptersListFragment());
                transaction.add(R.id.sub_sub_category_fragment,
                        new SubSubChaptersListFragment());
            }
            transaction.commit();
            setContentShown(true);
        }

    }

    static protected class Chapter {
        String chapterTitle;
        List<SubChapter> subchapterList;

        public Chapter(String chapterTitle, List<SubChapter> subchapterList) {
            this.chapterTitle = chapterTitle;
            this.subchapterList = subchapterList;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onChapterSelected(int position) {
        SubChaptersListFragment subChaptersListFrag = (SubChaptersListFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.sub_category_fragment);
        if (subChaptersListFrag != null) {
            subChaptersListFrag.updateList(position);
        } else {
            SubChaptersListFragment subChapterFragment = new SubChaptersListFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(SubChaptersListFragment.CHAPTER_POSITION, position);
            subChapterFragment.setArguments(args);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, subChapterFragment);
//          transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSubChapterSelected(int prev, int position) {
        SubSubChaptersListFragment subSubChaptersListFrag = (SubSubChaptersListFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.sub_sub_category_fragment);
        if (subSubChaptersListFrag != null) {
            subSubChaptersListFrag.updateList(prev, position);
        } else {
            SubSubChaptersListFragment subSubChapterFragment = new SubSubChaptersListFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putIntArray(SubSubChaptersListFragment.POSITIONS, new int[]{prev, position});
            subSubChapterFragment.setArguments(args);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, subSubChapterFragment);
//          transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();           
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (processTask != null && processTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
            processTask.cancel(true);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: guess it might be related to the transaction.add(), try using replace whenever you can

Comment: I used `replace` everywhere :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kirill Kulakov is right. `replace` instead of `add` should be used. I edited the code:

```
public class CompetitiveProgramming extends SherlockProgressFragment implements
        OnChapterSelectListener, OnSubChapterSelectListener {

    View mContentView;
    static public List<Chapter> chapterList = new ArrayList<Chapter>();
    private ProcessTask processTask = null;
    Fragment chapterFragment = null;
    Fragment subChapterFragment = null;
    Fragment subSubChapterFragment = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mContentView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.competitive_programming_exercise, container, false);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setContentShown(false);
        setContentView(mContentView);
        processTask = new ProcessTask();
        processTask.execute();
    }


    protected class ProcessTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // background task
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
            chapterFragment = new ChaptersListFragment();
            if (mContentView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, chapterFragment);
            } else {
                subChapterFragment = new SubChaptersListFragment();
                subSubChapterFragment = new SubSubChaptersListFragment();
                transaction.replace(R.id.category_fragment, chapterFragment);
                transaction.replace(R.id.sub_category_fragment, subChapterFragment);
                transaction.replace(R.id.sub_sub_category_fragment, subSubChapterFragment);
            }
            transaction.commit();
            setContentShown(true);
        }

    }

    static protected class Chapter {
        String chapterTitle;
        List<SubChapter> subchapterList;

        public Chapter(String chapterTitle, List<SubChapter> subchapterList) {
            this.chapterTitle = chapterTitle;
            this.subchapterList = subchapterList;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onChapterSelected(int position) {
        SubChaptersListFragment subChaptersListFrag = (SubChaptersListFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.sub_category_fragment);
        if (subChaptersListFrag != null) {
            subChaptersListFrag.updateList(position);
        } else {
            SubChaptersListFragment subChapterFragment = new SubChaptersListFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(SubChaptersListFragment.CHAPTER_POSITION, position);
            subChapterFragment.setArguments(args);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, subChapterFragment);
//          transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSubChapterSelected(int prev, int position) {
        SubSubChaptersListFragment subSubChaptersListFrag = (SubSubChaptersListFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.sub_sub_category_fragment);
        if (subSubChaptersListFrag != null) {
            subSubChaptersListFrag.updateList(prev, position);
        } else {
            SubSubChaptersListFragment subSubChapterFragment = new SubSubChaptersListFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putIntArray(SubSubChaptersListFragment.POSITIONS, new int[]{prev, position});
            subSubChapterFragment.setArguments(args);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, subSubChapterFragment);
//          transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();           
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (processTask != null && processTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
            processTask.cancel(true);
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this would help!

Comment: your ProcessTask isn't doing anything in the background, there's no point having it in an AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

You probably are adding the fragment in your `onResume()`, which is not what you want as each time you are resumed new fragment is added. Just fix your code's logic

Comment: Hello Sir, thanks for your answer! This is the question I asked and A--C gave me a pretty good solution to add fragment in backStack. I followed it. Please take a look and give me some example code what you have proposed. :)