# Bring to front existing fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

I have an application with n buttons. Each button create a new fragment and attach it to a view. So if i touch button A, B, C in that order the fragments FA, FB and FC are created and stacked:

FA,FB,FC

Now if i press A again a new fragment is created and stacked, so the stack become:

FA,FB,FC -> FA,FB,FC,**FA**

Is there a way to retreive an existing fragment from the stack (if exist) and bring it to front? So if i have the stack

FA,FB,FC

and press the "A" button again, the FA fragment is removed from backstack and put to front:

*FA*,FB,FC -> FB,FC,**FA**

and if I press "C" the stack become

FB,*FC*,FA -> FB,FA,**FC**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest reading the `FragmentManager` docs to see if there are any helpful methods there.

Comment: please, check this topic. hope it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737550/bring-fragment-to-front-no-fragment-recreation

Comment: I ended up making a custom Back Stack Manager that handle all fragment instances.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you need to obtain parent `View` where you placed your `Fragment`, or the root of your `Fragment`. Once you have it, just call the `bringToFront()` method that every `View` has, and you'll move that `View` to the front.

You could get your `View` or the container `View` of your `View` with the `findViewById()` method of your context.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet:

```
    activity?.supportFragmentManager?.let { manager ->
        val fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction()
        for (fragment in manager.fragments) {
            if (fragment is FragmentA) {
                fragmentTransaction.show(fragment)
            } else {
                fragmentTransaction.hide(fragment)
            }
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit()
    }
```