# why having youtubePlayer in recyclerView it stops playing after a millisecond

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, youtube-data-api

I have recyclerView with different type of items, and one of the item include youtube video ,I'm using YoutubePlayer .When I'm clicking on the video it starts playing but after a millisecond it stops.If I change to full screen mode it plays as expected. I receive this log

YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is obscured by android.widget.FrameLayout
It's item of recyclerView which contain youtubePlayer

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/youtubeFragment"
    android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
 val youtubeFragment = MainActivity.getMainActivity(context)?.supportFragmentManager?.findFragmentById(R.id.youtubeFragment)

  youtubeFragment.initialize(KEY,
    object : YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
      override fun onInitializationSuccess(provider: YouTubePlayer.Provider, youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer, b: Boolean) {
        youTubePlayer.loadVideo("5xVh-7ywKpE")
      }

      override fun onInitializationFailure(provider: YouTubePlayer.Provider,
                                           youTubeInitializationResult: YouTubeInitializationResult) {
      }
    })
```

Even I have tried commit fragment in class but it does not make difference

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/youtubeFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
    val fragmentManager = MainActivity.getMainActivity(viewBinding.root.context)?.supportFragmentManager
val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()

//add a fragment
val youtubeFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment()
fragmentTransaction?.add(R.id.youtubeFragment, youtubeFragment)
fragmentTransaction?.commit()





<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<data>
    <variable
        name="toolbarViewModel"
        type="se.ica.handla.ToolbarViewModel" />
</data>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/windowBackground"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="se.ica.handla.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbarLayout"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_top_level"
        app:toolbarViewModel="@{toolbarViewModel}" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/toolbarLayout"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/news_list"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: xml which have recyclerView !!

Comment: @ Mohamed Embaby I have updated

Comment: Try to put recyclerView above ConstraintLayout

Comment: @Mohamed Embaby I removed ConstraitLayout but it still the same situation

Comment: humm, try recyclerView.bringToFront(); and fragment.bringToFront();

Comment: @Mohamed Embaby I add bringToFront for recyclerView, but fragment doesn't have the function bringToFront() and adding for recyclerView it doesn't work

Comment: ConstraintLayout which contains recyclerView ConstraintLayout.bringToFront()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162101/discussion-between-i-ss-and-mohamed-embaby).

Comment: @ Mohamed Embaby Thanks so much

Comment: Me also same problem...after integrating youtube fragment inside recycler view, player getting stuck wiith some overlay message.

Comment: @I.S  Can u please help me on this.

Comment: @basha do you see `Let us continue this discussion in chat.` If yes go there and maybe you can find necessary information if not, let me know I will send you it

Answer (score 0):

As the YouTube Player API documentation says

> Playback has been stopped due to a view overlaying the player. It is
>   not permitted to overlay views on top of the player while it is
>   playing video.

I suppose you can bring the `fragment` to top programmatically see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20737550/7569106) to relate, though this way is not recommended

Another way is to handle your `xml` well, and keep the `fragment` in the top of other Views

Comment: but there is nothing over the fragment ,even I added translationZ but it doesn't help

Comment: can you post your xml file ?