# How to return back to the previously open activity and fragmen

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have 2 activity Activity-1 and Activity-2 ..... Activity-2 has fragments fragment-1 and fragment-2 and fragment-3 The work flow is.. Activity 1 ---> Activity 2---> fragment 1 ---> fragment 2 ---> fragment --->3 but i am trying back the following sequence.. fragment 3 ---> fragment 2 ---> fragment --->1 Activity 2 ---> Activity 1

i have used

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

it shows an back button left of the ActionBarActivity

i can get the click event here...

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            //do your own thing here

            return true;
        default: return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);  
        }
    }
```

what should i do ?????

Answer (score 1):

When applying your fragment transactions, you need to make sure they are added to the fragment back stack with the `addToBackStack()` method. Then the framework will do the work of unwinding the fragments before finishing the host activity.

You can read more in the [Fragments Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#Replace).

Answer (score 1):

```
popBackStack and addToBackStack methods will do. See links for details:
```

[How to resume Fragment from BackStack if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305945/how-to-resume-fragment-from-backstack-if-exists)
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to use addtoBackStack to add a fragment to backstack, for activity that will be done by default and not for fragments. See the video in the following link. You will get the complete picture:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZbKKxYUOH-c&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW4lMlpHgL7UNQSGMERcDzHo