# Fragment dismiss after tap on Back button

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two Fragments - `FragmentA` and `FragmentB`.

I try to show `FragmentB` from `FragmentA`.

```
    FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB();

    MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    int fragmentContainer = activity.getFragmentContainer();

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(fragmentContainer, fragmentB);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

### MainActivity

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        fragmentA = new FragmentA(getSupportFragmentManager());
        //...

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(FRAGMENT_CONTAINER,fragmentA);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

FragmentB is showed, but when i click on back button i have a next situation - FragmentB was dismissed, but FragmentA not showed.

Why this happens and what i need to edit to get a correct result?

Comment: try swapping the replace line with the addToBackStack

Comment: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305945/how-to-resume-fragment-from-backstack-if-exists) .. See this.. This will helps you..

Comment: @Heinrisch no effect.

Comment: fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null).commit();

Comment: try calling popbackstact in ondestroyview of your fragment

Comment: @Elltz fragment was not destroyed. I logged this.

Comment: Try replacing 'replace' with 'add' in this line fragmentTransaction.replace(fragmentContainer, fragmentB); inside fragment A. If you use replace, your fragmentA will get replaced with fragmentB. If you use add along with addtobackstack, fragmentB will be added over existing fragment

Answer (score 0):

```
getActivity().getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

use this it may be works inside fragmentB

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [New Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30371140/fragment-dismiss-after-tap-on-back-button?noredirect=1#comment48832361_30371140) for provided [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305945/how-to-resume-fragment-from-backstack-if-exists).

All that we need it's just add a

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
  if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1){
    finish();
  }
  else {
    super.onBackPressed();
  }
}
```

and

```
private void replaceFragment (Fragment fragment){
  String backStateName =  fragment.getClass().getName();
  String fragmentTag = backStateName;

  FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
  boolean fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate (backStateName, 0);

  if (!fragmentPopped && manager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag) == null){ //fragment not in back stack, create it.
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, fragmentTag);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
    ft.commit();
  } 
}
```

and manage fragments in activity.

So if we need a swap fragments just call :

```
replaceFragment(new MySwappingFragment());
```