# Update NavigationView state when user goes back to previous fragment

Tags: android, fragment, navigationview

I'm using the NavigationView drawer in my app. I'm trying go back to the previous Fragment if the user press back button. This code works well:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();        
    Fragment fr = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.flContent);

    if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 ) {
        fm.popBackStackImmediate();
    }
    else {
        finish();
    }        
}
```

But my NavigationView doesn't change. How can I update the NavigationView state (check the correct fragment, change title, and so on), so it can reflect the changes in my app?

Answer (score 0):

You should implement Back Navigation using addToBackStack method. Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-fragments).

Comment: This answers only the question when to update. I could also use onBackPressed(). The main question is which position should be highlighted in the drawer?

Comment: check the first answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305945/how-to-resume-fragment-from-backstack-if-exists)

Answer (score 0):

I created a workaround: When drawer is created or menuItem is clicked, I'm storing the current menuItem:

```
private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
    // Storing "home" menuItem when app starts
    storedMenuItem = navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0);

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    selectDrawerItem(menuItem);

                    // Storing menuItem when another item is selected
                    storedMenuItem = menuItem;

                    return true;
                }
            });
}
```

So in my onBackPressed method I'm doing this:

```
  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    selectDrawerItem(storedMenuItem);
  }
```

No changes on selectDrawerItem (I used [this](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer) code)

I don't know if it's a good solution, but it's working very well.

Comment: this works only for first back, if i open 3 menuitem and then press 2 times back doesen't works