# How to get back to previous fragment in Android

Tags: android, fragment

I want to move back to my previous fragment when I click on the back button. What I am doing is not working.

The code for fragment replacement:

```
Fragment fragment=new MyFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
    .beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in,R.anim.slide_out);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

The code for catch hit of Back button:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                getActivity().finish();
                getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_enter, R.anim.slide_exit);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I have also tried

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

Comment: fragmentTransaction.addtobackstack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());

Comment: I have already implemented but still not works

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305945/how-to-resume-fragment-from-backstack-if-exists

Comment: When i write this my back button stop working

Comment: use addToBackStack(null) back handeling back press event in fragment

Comment: you are replace all fragment.so

Comment: Again it stop working see what i have done:-

Comment: Fragment fragment=new MyFragment();
               FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
               FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                        .beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in,R.anim.slide_out);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
                 backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(backStateName);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

Comment: have you code any onbackpressed?

Comment: can you tell me what exactly flow what you want to do,

Comment: I am using onResume as I have posted

Comment: I simply want back button when click move to previous fragment

Comment: just use add fragment instead of replace

Comment: because you want to back that fragment. if you replace fragment then previous fragment instance not stay more so if you want it back then you have to get it using tag. But in your case i think you have to use add fragment and use add tobackstack hide method.

Comment: i have posted example try like that

Comment: and comment your code which you write in on resume

Comment: Hello,Actually what i am having is one fragment class having view pager,recycler view and when click on back button,this activity do not gone

Answer (score 0):

Change like this this mat help

```
Fragment fragment=new MyFragment();
               FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
               FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                        .beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in,R.anim.slide_out);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment).addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Let me know if any error

Comment: .addToBackStack(null); add in each fragment you want to listen back button controle

Comment: Nothing happend

Comment: Hey its working in one fragment but not when i replace fragment from recycleadapter so can u tell me solution for this also.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like below.

```
   DetailsFragment detailsFragment = new DetailsFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("ID", Id);
                    detailsFragment.setArguments(bundle);

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.detail_container, detailsFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
            transaction.hide(DetailsFragment.this);
            transaction.commit();
```