# Fragment hardware back button event called twice

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to implement back navigation through my fragments which are called in specific order: `A`->`B`->`C` and by going back with hardware button I would like them to remain order.

I am using `fragmenttransaction.replace` in order to switch fragment with no `addToBackStack` because it made my `ActionBarMenu` to misbehave.

Problem is that when I am on fragment `C` back button is going back directly to `A`. I found out that it is because `click` event is executed twice I am going to `B` and directly to `A`.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    setOnBackButtonPresed();
}

private void setOnBackButtonPresed() {
    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener( new View.OnKeyListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey( View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event )
        {
            if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
            {
                goBackToDays();
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
    } );
}

private void goBackToDays() {
    Log.e("fragmentC", "executing on back action")
}
```

logcat result:

```
03-15 08:37:17.353 21245-21245/com.test E/fragmentC: executing on back action
03-15 08:37:17.390 21245-21245/com.test E/fragmentC: executing on back action
```

Can anyone give me a hint how I can avoide twice button events?

Comment: Can you post a basic setup of project on github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things:

1. Even though you're `replacing` fragments, the old `OnKeyListener` stays there (and get's fired up later on). Try removing the old `OnKeyListener` on switching fragments.
2. Just as [S-lightning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42805635/1993204) pointed out, you need to bare in mind that there are two actions associated with a key event (`KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and `KeyEvent.ACTION_UP`).

Answer (score 3):

I think "click event is executed twice" because you call both event ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP. Try this

```
@Override
    public boolean onKey( View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event )
    {
        if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction()== KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            goBackToDays();
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: syntax error: `Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'android.view.KeyEvent','int'`

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. Edited! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things

1. "it made my ActionBarMenu to misbehave." FIX this issue.
2. Override `onBackPressed()` on your Activity and find find out your current loaded fragment and replace with whichever you want.

   ```
   Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_view_container);
   if (fragment instanceof FragmentThree) {
         //replace with your fragment ie. FragmentTwo
   } else if (fragment instanceof FragmentTwo) {
         //replace with your fragment ie. FragmentOne
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Return `true` if you want to "absorb" the key event and stop it from propagating up to the Activity, which has its own `onBackPressed()` implementation.

```
if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
{
    goBackToDays();
    return true; // <-- should be TRUE, not FALSE
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the `onBackPressed()` method in hosting activity.
do like this.

```
private void replaceFragment (Fragment fragment){
  String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();

  FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
  boolean fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);

  if (!fragmentPopped){ //fragment not in back stack, create it.
     FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
     ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
     ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
     ft.commit();
  }
}
.

.

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
  if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1){
    finish();
  }
  else {
    super.onBackPressed();
  }
}
```

Here is the well explained answer. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18306258/5882539)