# Back Button in ActionBar of App

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

Generally switching from one activity to another activity hamburger icon is replaced with back arrow. I want to control the functionality of that arrow. I have seen many contents here but most of them were related to hardware's back button. How can I control that?

**I am trying the functionality in case of fragments. Also I have Navigation drawer attached with the hamburger icon.**

I tried this-

```
if(id == android.R.id.home){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_container, new AmbulanceMap()).commit();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Book A Ride");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    }
```

but doesnt work as I hoped.

**I want my back button to change the fragmentto previous fragment.**

Comment: when you create onCreateOption menu and its itemselected ....u can use android.R.id.home id for controlling that back button.

Comment: I tried that but it is not working it just open the drawer attached.

Comment: did you add getSupportToolbar().setDisplayHomeUpAsEnabled(true);

Comment: yes i did that.. everything is working well and good except the back button

Comment: What exactly do you want your back button to do?

Comment: I want my back button to change the fragmentto previous fragment.

Comment: you can do that with saving your fragment in stack ...thats what i think can work.  addToBackstack....try it ...nd pass the fragment name in its paramater...it should work

Comment: try this ....maybe it can help ..my previous answer meant this ....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305945/how-to-resume-fragment-from-backstack-if-exists

Comment: study about up navigation in fragments that will help you

Comment: Sahil tried that too.. but result didnt change.. but will try it once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem once. Just like you, things like checking if Android.R.id.home is clicked didn't work.
But I solved it using that:

Set navigation listener to toolbar:

```
toolbar.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(v -> onBackPressed());
```

If it should be within fragment:

1. Create an public method in activity.
2. In fragment's onAttach (or later) cast getActivity() to your activity and call method you was defined previously.

Example:

```
// YourActivity
public void setHomeListener(OnLickListener listener){
    toolbar.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(listener);
}

//Fragment's onCreate
((YourActivity)getActivity()).setHomeListener(v -> onBackPressed());

//Fragment's onDestroy
 ((YourActivity)getActivity()).setHomeListener(null);
```

And, of course, set home us up enabled to show back arrow.

**EDIT**

if you don't use labmdas u should use:

```
(YourActivity)getActivity()).setHomeListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        YourFragment.this.onBackPressed();
    }
});
```

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala which code do you exaclty need?

Comment: setting up navigationClick listener

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala, what is unclear? May be where you can find drawer Toggle?

Comment: when i am setting up listener it is giving me to add On click listener only

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala do you sure you set listener to instance of ActionBarDrawerToggle? Because it has this method.

Comment: yes. i said i found that listener which you mention but int the bracket u wrote v -> onBackPressed() , this i dint get

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala oh, sorry its lambdas, just wait a bit.

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala no effect means onClick do not called?

Comment: I mean to say that what we intend to do doesnot happen. instead drawer opens.

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala I've mistaken a bit, you should set listener to toolbar, not toggle. And, its better to call fragmentManager.popBackStack()(instead of onBackPressed())

Comment: Thanx for helping.. pls change the toggle to toolbar in solution

Answer (score 0):

The back button of the ActionBar is a menuItem so you need to override onOptionsItemSelected like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            //Your back button logic here
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Also don´t forget to add `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` after setting the Toolbar

Comment: I tried that but it is not working it just open the drawer attached.

Comment: can you copy the code of your Activity that contains that Toolbar?

Comment: I dint get you. what actually you want to see? I can post.

Comment: I want to take a look at the code of your Activity .