# FragmentPagerAdapter to onbackpressed

Tags: android, android-studio, fragmentpageradapter

I have one activity and four fragments in it.the problem is that when i start an activity from any fragment Navigation goes to back first fragment after that.Also when i call onactivityforresult after that navigation comes back to first fragment. 
MainActivity Code is :

```
mPagerAdapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {
        private final Fragment[] mFragments = new Fragment[]{
                new RecentPostsFragment(),
                new DonorsFragment(),
                new PlaceActivity(),
                new MyTopPostsFragment(),

        };
        private final String[] mFragmentNames = new String[]{
                getString(R.string.heading_recent),
                getString(R.string.heading_donors),
                getString(R.string.heading_nearby),
                getString(R.string.heading_my_top_posts)
        };

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragments[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragments.length;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentNames[position];
        }
    };
    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```

Fragment code is :

```
       @Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_posts, container, false);
   // [START create_database_reference]
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    // [END create_database_reference]

    mRecycler = rootView.findViewById(R.id.messages_list);
    mRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: so what do you want to do?

Comment: hello,
i want that resume to same fragment.

Comment: it always comes back to first fragment i want that i should pop the last fragment where i have called activity.

Comment: This link will help you :-
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305945/how-to-resume-fragment-from-backstack-if-exists

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
private void wannaReplaceFragment (Fragment fragment){
  String backState = fragment.getClass().getName();

  FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
  boolean fragmentPopped = fm.popBackStackImmediate (backState, 0);

  if (!fragmentPopped){
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(backState);
    ft.commit();
  }
}
```

when replacing a Fragment, use the `popBackStackImmediate()` method. Once you can take guide from this link :- [How to resume Fragment from BackStack if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305945/how-to-resume-fragment-from-backstack-if-exists)

Comment: where i should use this?

Comment: @AsimDogar  share your MainActivity class here I will tell you where

Comment: MainActivity Code is shared in question

Comment: @AsimDogar use this method in onCreate in your MainActivity

Comment: this is for one fragment i have to implement on all fragments i'm using arrrays of fragments

Comment: @AsimDogar  that's why I want to see your whole MainActivity java code

Comment: Full code for MainActivity.java https://gist.github.com/asimdogar/e2dfc2ce4a9330cfee412cae6bafd8e1