# Recyclerview not reloading intended fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

currently implementing a recyclerview inside a fragment. previously was done using activity -recyclerview, without any problem. but with fragment i found weird problem.

**Problem** - 
when i load home for the first time, my recyclerview would load normally. But after changing to different fragment and back to home, my recyclerview would't load but stuck to the fragment i load previously.

could someone clarify what i did wrong?

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
private List<FeedData> feedList = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private FeedAdapter fAdapter;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public HomeFragment () {
}

public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    fAdapter = new FeedAdapter(feedList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager fLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(fLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(fAdapter);

   prepareMovieData();

    return rootView;
}
```

preparemovie()

```
private void prepareMovieData() {
    FeedData feedData = new FeedData("Mad Max: Fury Road", "Action & Adventure", "2015");
    feedList.add(feedData);

    feedData = new FeedData("Inside Out", "Animation, Kids & Family", "2015");
    feedList.add(feedData);

    feedData = new FeedData("Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens", "Action", "2015");
    feedList.add(feedData);

    feedData = new FeedData("Shaun the Sheep", "Animation", "2015");
    feedList.add(feedData);

    fAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

HomeFragment

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".fragment.HomeFragment">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

sorry for the noob question, just learning. most code are follow closely with stackoverflow and androidhive.
*Attached are gif that replicate what the problem look like.

[via GIPHY](https://giphy.com/gifs/8car6SSZ45BsF8GSpK)

Comment: may you provide the code where you inflate the fragment? so it appears to the user

Comment: + share code for prepareMovieData()

Comment: sorry. u mean the main.java(getFragment()) stuff or xml where i put recyclerview?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are replacing one fragment with other using:fragmentmanager.replace() you also need to add fragment to backstack. for better understanding see:
[How to resume Fragment from BackStack if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305945/how-to-resume-fragment-from-backstack-if-exists)