# Navigation Architecture Component Push And Pop Functionality

Tags: android, navigation, android-architecture-components, navigationcontroller

Using the navigation controller, we can navigate to another fragment easily but each time it will create new fragment

for eg navigate Fragment A --> B --> C then I pop fragment A then it will create new object of fragment A rather than  resume to Fragment A.

I want this type of functionality using a navigation controller.
[How to resume Fragment from BackStack if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305945/how-to-resume-fragment-from-backstack-if-exists/18306258)

Comment: As far as I knew you need another lib for that job. Kindly go through below article 
                  https://proandroiddev.com/why-i-will-not-use-architecture-navigation-component-97d2ad596b36

Comment: @Hitesh Dhamshaniya will you please tell me which lib we need to use?