# How to run CountDownTimer in Fragment

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments, countdowntimer

I have one User Activity class which has drawer menu (includes home page, my profil etc..). When user clicks the one of the menu item, I will load fragment such as HomePageFragment, MyProfilFragment etc..

Here is the code example:

```
public void navigationItemSelectedListener(DrawerLayout drawerLayout, NavigationView navigationView) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(menuItem -> {
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    int menuId = menuItem.getItemId();
    switch (menuId){
        case R.id.home_menu_item:
            loadFragment(new HomePageFragment());
            break;
// goes like that
```

Here is the loadFragment:

```
public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.user_page_activity_frame_layout, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Now I have run CountDownTimer(60 seconds) in HomePageFragment, when counter is 0, I will run some methods().

However **I can not do that.** Because each time user navigates new item, then when back to the HomePage menu item, new HomePageFragment() is creating, therefore CountDownTimer starts with 60s again and again. What I want CounDownTimer to run even if user navigates another menu.

Note that, I had tried to create HomePageFragment attribute as global. But it didn't work. (Like 2 timer counts down. One says 60-59... another says 30-29 ...)

Comment: @monsereo has this anwer solved your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53661931/7360848. If so, please accept it, if not, let me know

Comment: @TouhidulIslam thanks, I could solve via creating the timer in my host activity.

Comment: if it solved the problem, you might as well accept the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem here is, your `Fragment` gets destroyed every time user navigates to another item.

To solve this

1.Either Create the Timer in your host activity instead the fragment, maybe inside `navigationItemSelectedListener()`

2.Make sure your fragment doesn't get destroyed everytime. Check [How to resume Fragment from BackStack if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305945/how-to-resume-fragment-from-backstack-if-exists)