# How to disable the back button press in fragment but allow the fragment itself to implement the back pressing logics

Tags: android, stack, fragment, onbackpressed

I have the following XML -

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_checkout_top_view">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_checkout_stages_viewgroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_discount_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marketplace_15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                android:text="@string/activity_checkout_checkout"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_first_stage_viewgroup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_first_stage_textview"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marketplace_15dp"
                    android:background="@color/color_black"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/activity_checkout_1"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_billing_address_textview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                    android:text="@string/activity_checkout_billing_address"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/billing_shipping__address_layout_bottom_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marketplace_15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                android:background="@color/activity_checkout_stages_line" />


            <!-- Billing layout -->
            <include
                android:id="@+id/checkout_activity_billing_address_layout_include"
                layout="@layout/fragment_checkout_billing_shipping"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_billing_address_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_second_stage_viewgroup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_second_stage_textview"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marketplace_15dp"
                    android:background="@color/activity_checkout_unselected_checkout_stage_color"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/activity_checkout_2"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_black" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_shipping_address_textview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                    android:text="@string/activity_checkout_shipping_address"
                    android:textColor="@color/activity_checkout_unselected_checkout_stage_color"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_shipping_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marketplace_15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                android:background="@color/activity_checkout_stages_line" />

            <!-- Shipping layout -->
            <include
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_shipping_address_layout_include"
                layout="@layout/fragment_checkout_billing_shipping"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_shipping_address_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_third_stage_viewgroup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_third_stage_textview"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marketplace_15dp"
                    android:background="@color/activity_checkout_unselected_checkout_stage_color"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/activity_checkout_3"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_black" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_shipping_method_textview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                    android:text="@string/activity_checkout_shipping_method"
                    android:textColor="@color/activity_checkout_unselected_checkout_stage_color"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_payment_method_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marketplace_15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                android:background="@color/activity_checkout_stages_line" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_shipping_method_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_forth_stage_viewgroup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marketplace_15dp"
                    android:background="@color/activity_checkout_unselected_checkout_stage_color"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/activity_checkout_4"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_black" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                    android:text="@string/activity_checkout_payment_method"
                    android:textColor="@color/activity_checkout_unselected_checkout_stage_color"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_payment_information_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marketplace_15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                android:background="@color/activity_checkout_stages_line" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_fifth_stage_viewgroup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_fifth_stage"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marketplace_15dp"
                    android:background="@color/activity_checkout_unselected_checkout_stage_color"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/activity_checkout_5"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_black" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_payment_information"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                    android:text="@string/activity_checkout_payment_information"
                    android:textColor="@color/activity_checkout_unselected_checkout_stage_color"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <View
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_confirm_order_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marketplace_15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                android:background="@color/activity_checkout_stages_line" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_payment_information_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_sixth_stage_viewgroup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_sixth_stage"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marketplace_15dp"
                    android:background="@color/activity_checkout_unselected_checkout_stage_color"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/activity_checkout__6"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_black" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_confirm_information_textview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                    android:text="@string/activity_checkout_confirm_information"
                    android:textColor="@color/activity_checkout_unselected_checkout_stage_color"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_confirm_information_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marketplace_15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                android:background="@color/activity_checkout_stages_line" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_confirm_information_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Which looks like this - (This is not the entire XML as shown in the picture, but only the one relevant to the question)

[image]

The way it works is that for every FrameLayout you see in the XML I inflate another Fragment inside it, in turns for each stage respectively.

Inside each fragment, when I need to dismiss that fragment from the UI, I call the following code -

```
activity?.onBackPressed()
```

Which dismisses the relevant Fragment and after that I pop a new one.

The problem I am currently facing is the ability to close the fragment with a single back press, which is bad for the UI. I could easily dismiss the `onBackPressed()` ability, but than how would I be able to tell each fragment to dismiss itself?

I need a way to block the fragment from reacting to backpress but still have the ability to remove itself from the backstack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want to dismiss a Fragment, call `getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate()` instead of `onBackPressed()`.

Answer (score -2):

Use BackStack and push , pop fragment

Comment: Please be more informative, I can't do anything with this comment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305945/how-to-resume-fragment-from-backstack-if-exists