# Unable to send fragments back in Java

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am currently developing an Android mobile application and I encountered a problem. Although I tried and searched many sites and resources in stackoverflow, I could not find the solution. I am sharing my codes below.

What I want to do i want the fragments to go back when the back button is pressed, but it goes back to the activity part. As a result of how many Fragments are clicked, it returns to the activity part. What can I do. Sorry for my missing English.

**InternalFilesActivity**

```
 public class InternalFilesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private FragmentManager manager;
        private FragmentTransaction transaction;
        private File[] files;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_internal_files);
    
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File directory = new File(path);
            files = directory.listFiles();
    
            manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            Fragment fr = FilesFragment.newInstance(files);
            transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fr);
            transaction.commit();
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if (manager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
                manager.popBackStackImmediate();
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }
    }
```

**FilesFragment**

```
public class FilesFragment extends Fragment {
    private static File[] frFiles;

    public FilesFragment() {
    }

    public static FilesFragment newInstance(File[] files) {
        FilesFragment fragment = new FilesFragment();
        frFiles = files;
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_files, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ListView internalList = view.findViewById(R.id.lv_internal);
        InternalListAdapter adapter = new InternalListAdapter(frFiles, getContext(), getActivity());
        internalList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**InternalListAdapter**

```
public class InternalListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public File[] dataList;
    public Context context;
    public FragmentActivity activity;


    public InternalListAdapter(File[] dataList, Context context, FragmentActivity activity) {
        this.dataList = dataList;
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dataList.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.internal_list_item, parent, false);

        TextView fileName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_file_name);
        fileName.setText(dataList[position].getName());

        ImageView listImage = convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_list_image);
        if (dataList[position].isDirectory()) {
            listImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_directory);
        } else {
            listImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_file);
        }

        LinearLayout listItemLayout = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ll_list_item);
        listItemLayout.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            if (dataList[position].isDirectory()) {
                createFragment(position);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    private void createFragment(int position) {
        FragmentManager manager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment fr = FilesFragment.newInstance(dataList[position].listFiles());
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fr);
        transaction.commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: So where are you calling `addToBackStack()`? It doesn't look like any of your `FragmentTransaction`s is being added to the back stack at all.

Comment: I'm adding it in the createFragment() method, but not in the code I shared

Answer (score 0):

in back press you have implemented `Fragment` popping up from back stack, but you are not adding your fragments to back stack in fact

use [`addToBackStack(someName)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)) method for putting your fragments in there and then your back press should start working (more info in [this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305945/how-to-resume-fragment-from-backstack-if-exists))

```
        manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fr = FilesFragment.newInstance(files);
        transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.addToBackStack("initialFragment"); // also may be null
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fr);
        transaction.commit();
```

Comment: I've tried these before but it didn't work. I tried the addToBackStack () method with 'null' and 'tag', but it didn't work either way. @snachmsm

Answer (score 0):

check my answer.

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
          int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
            if(count==1){
                finish();
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode,event);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

The problem was that I used fragment as an instance. The problem was resolved when I created and used a new object.

```
private static File[] files;

public FilesFragment(File[] files) {
  this.files = files;     
}
```

I used the `new FileManager()` code instead of `FileFragment.newInstance()`