# RecyclerView Not showing as I am expecting ANDROID STUDIO JAVA

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, picasso

I am using fragment to change the App Ui (Ex: Favourite, Home, Setting fragments in the MainActivity).

Home fragment is responsible for loading the images using recyclerview (Using Picasso library)

When I am switching to different fragment (Home => Setting) and the switching back to Home fragment then the recyclerview is loading from start.

Problem: **Doesn't able to cache the images into storage using Picasso and the recyclerview is showing items from start, I want to show the items where it's left before switching the fragments.**

***Please use JAVA language***

Comment: Might be you are recreating that fragment hence try adding that fragment in back stack and when you are coming back to home use instance from back stack


you can check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18306258/7979054